# Displaying Spinner with data items with different typeface

Tags: android

In my app I am displaying a spinner that contains different font styles e.g. if the font name is US DNealian than it should get displayed with the same typeface as well. I know how to set typeface of particular view by view.setTypeface(tf) but I am using an array arr_fonts to fill ArrayList and that ArrayList will fill the adapter for spinner. Below is the code snippet I am using.

-> String array for filling ArrayList

```
private String arr_fonts[] = {"US: D'Nealian", "US: D'Nealian Cursive", "US: Zaner-Bloser", "US: Zaner-Bloser Cursive",
            "Aus: NSW/ACT", "Aus: NSW/ACT Cursive", "Aus: Qld Beginners", "Aus: Qld Cursive", "Aus: SA Beginners", "Aus: SA Cursive",
            "Aus: Tas Beginners", "Aus: Tas Cursive", "Aus: Vic/NT/WA", "Aus: Vic/NT/WA Cursive", "WA Sassoon", "WA Sassoon Infant",
            "NZ Beginners","UK Beginners", "UK Cursive", "Century Gothic (HWT)"};
```

->Arraylist for filling adapter

```
ARRLIST_FONTS = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr_fonts));
```

private void set_font_name_Adapter() {

```
    sp_fonts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spFont);

     font_name_Adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ARRLIST_FONTS)
              {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ((TextView) v).setTextSize(12);
                    ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    return v;
          }
```

};

```
        font_name_Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sp_fonts.setAdapter(font_name_Adapter);

        sp_fonts.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                font = ARRLIST_FONTS.get(arg2);

                }


                System.out.println("Selected item is ................."+font);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });

}
```

I have .ttf for all the font names. But I dont know how to change typeface of each item in spinner individually.

Can anyone suggest any thing or any link or good tutorial for the same.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as to set custom Typeface for all TextView's in spinner :

```
Typeface typeface;
font_name_Adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ARRLIST_FONTS)
       {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
               View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
               ((TextView) v).setTextSize(12);
               ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                if(position<=ARRLIST_FONTS.size()){
                 typeface = 
                  Typeface.createFromAsset(Your_Current_Activity.this.getAssets(),
                               "fonts/yourfontname.ttf"); 
                     ((TextView) v).setTypeface(typeface);
                   }

                    return v;
     }
```

Comment: In Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                               ARRLIST_FONTS.get(position)); where am I supposed to give .ttf file to set typeface? The code you have provided  wont change the typeface of that item.

Comment: @nidhi : means you have any issue in this line?

Comment: @nidhi : you have fonts in assest folder or in any other place?

Comment: Yeah....... it is not changing the font typeface. And obviously it will not because we have to provide font.ttf in order to change the typeface; whereas here we are not providing it any typeface. I hope I am making myself clear. Please let me know if it is still confusing. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: in assets folder only. If i run the suggested code, It throws exception: 12-20 18:38:29.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1252): java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Comment: @nidhi : sorry here some miss understanding actually i think you have all fonts path in ARRLIST_FONTS arraylist . now see my edit answer

Comment: I appreciate the time you are sparing for this issue, but I am afraid  it is still not working and also let me elaborate bit more on my issue as I know it is very confusing but that is how it is........... can't help it!!!!!!  I want that typeface for each item in the arraylist should change acc to its name............e.g. the first item in my array list is US DNealian so for that the font typeface should be DNealian.ttf,the second one in the list is DNealian Cursive so its typeface should be DNealian Cursive.ttf and so on. I hope this will aid in understanding where I am stuck. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21495/discussion-between--k-and-nidhi)

Answer (score 1):

First, create a new XML file in your res/layout directory called "my_spinner_style.xml", and put in something like the following content:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="9pt"
android:singleLine="True"
android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

Then in your code, use something like this:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
mySpinnerArrayAdapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.my_spinner_style); mySpinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Normally you would create a new ArrayAdapter for the second line, but in this case you need to create a custom ArrayAdapter and override the methods that get the TextView from our custom spinner style.

So, you need to put in the code for your custom ArrayAdapter, like so:
private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

```
public TextView getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
v.setTypeface(myFont);
return v;
}

public TextView getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
v.setTypeface(myFont);
return v;
}

}
```

The font you want to use needs to reside in the assets/fonts directory, and you access it like so:

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
```